# Поиск значения в выполняем скрипте python

Tags: python, search

Столкнулся с проблемой поиска значения. При выполнения скрипта генерируется hex большой длинны.

c38506eb203**f4474e032f0449d**a723ff3e817cfc41e04a01c61a110f3a5f3a4a131ef28cd5c8dce5b2324d366f49f720ffbb340387ef310e8a4a131ef28cd5c8dce59a36899e5e4034ac4e032f0449da723ff3ea4a131ef28cd5c8dce5

Мне нужно что-бы скрипт искал мне нужное значение в этом hex.

К примеру если я ищу это **f4474e032f0449d** и оно есть в строке, то hex полностью записывается в файл. С записью проблем нету а вот поиск не могу сделать. Ищет только целую строку.

Вот сам код

```
import bitcoin
import ecdsa, codecs
wanted = ("8", "16", "44") 
while True:
    hex_key = bitcoin.random_key()
    key_bytes = codecs.decode (hex_key, 'hex')
    key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string (key_bytes, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1).verifying_key
    bytes_key = key.to_string()
    curve_hex = codecs.encode(bytes_key, 'hex')
    print (hex_key + ' ' + curve_hex)
if str(curve_hex).find(wanted)!=-1:
        dosya2 = open("br2.txt")
        dosya2.write(hex_key + ' ' + curve_hex)
        dosya2.close()
```

в этом коде присутствует 8, 16, 44. Нужно чтобы данный код, находя эти значения в строке, записывал их в файл. Он не хочет работать.

Comment: что нужно найти-то? фрагмент строки в другой строке или целую строку в кортеже?

Comment: Попробуйте работу с регулярными выражениями, а именно в с библиотекой [re](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/modul-re-dlja-reguljarnyh-vyrazhenij-v-python)

Comment: Да, нужно найти фрагмент строки  в кортеже и записать целую строку эту в которой он найден.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вообще этот код запускали?

- `hex` - это встроенная функция питона, не называйте так переменные
- `os.urandom` - это функция, её нужно вызывать, чтобы получить значение: `os.urandom()`
- И она возвращает уже байты, их не нужно переводить в байты (а, это вы уже убрали из кода, я смотрю)
- `str()` от байтов - вы смотрели, что на выходе даёт? Совсем не то, что вы пытаетесь искать, вы никогда ничего не найдёте, там внутри бэкслэши и прочий мусор. Ищите что-то такое: `bytes.fromhex("340387ef310e8a4a131ef28cd5c8dce5")`
- Ну и главное - перебором случайных значений такие длинные конкретные последовательности вы будете искать до конца времени жизни Вселенной и всё-равно не найдёте

Comment: Этот код я привел для примера. Хотел показать что функция wanted работает только с целым значением. Допустим если уменьшить генерируемый хеш до 5 значений для теста, то он находит легко эти 5 значений. Но если пытаться искать не большое значение он не ищет. Весь код большой просто и подгружает еще другие скрипты, не стал сюда его писать. Просто показал грубо основную проблему. Что не могу понять как сделать это.

Comment: ??? Какая ФУНКЦИЯ wanted ??? И что значит "не большое значение"? А что "до 5 значений" -  это "большое"?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, вы не только код не запускали перед тем, как его сюда зачем-то писать (это просто неуважение к тем, кто будет вам помогать), так вы еще и Python не изучали, прежде чем решили хэши разгадывать.

Только потому что вы новичок на сайте (а новичков тут стараются не обижать) даю вам наводку:

```
wanted='f4474e032f0449d' 
hx='c38506eb203f4474e032f0449da723ff3e817cfc41e04a01c61a110f3a5f3a4a131ef28cd5c8dce5b2324d366f49f720ffbb340387ef310e8a4a131ef28cd5c8dce59a36899e5e4034ac4e032f0449da723ff3ea4a131ef28cd5c8dce5'
if str(hx).find(wanted)!=-1:
    print (hx[str(hx).find(wanted):str(hx).find(wanted)+len(wanted)])
else:
    print ('Не найдено')
```

Comment: можно использовать `wandet in str(hx)`

Comment: а зачем так сложно написано ``print(wanted)``?

Comment: Добавил рабочий скрипт на примере биткоина. Просто у меня скрипт на другой валюте он увесистый., сюда много добавлять бы пришлось. Извиняюсь что сразу так не сделал. В общем суть нужно что-бы он находил в любом месте hex, заданные значения и записывал hex целиком в котором нашел. На данный момент он ищет только целостные значение.

Comment: @Эникейщик -  Ну, во-первых, потому что это подсказка, а не решение.  Во-вторых, в приведенном варианте значение "вытягиваются" из строки, что-бы показать, что они вытягиваются. И что-бы наглядно проверить тождественность. А в вашем варианте -  просто берется исходная строка.

Comment: @Константин -  ищет ровно то, что вы показали в примере в исходном сообщении. "искал мне нужное значение в этом hex" Вот скрипт и ищет. Если вы писали одно а имели ввиду нечто другое -  то  сформулируйте свою мысль (вопрос) корректно.

Comment: Я проверил ваш скрипт, он ищет. Но если hx заменить не на статику а генерирующий скрипт. То он уже не ищет значение даже если поставит в поиске 2х значное число. Которое в любом случае должно найтись. Я ваш скрипт внедрил в шапку все исправив. Но как видно он не находит  wanted = ("8", "16", "44")  и не сохраняет.

Comment: @Константин Очевидно, что вам нужно взять учебник и разобраться с базовыми элементами языка. Чтобы научиться понимать то, что именно делает код, и не искать кортеж в строке.

Comment: @ Константин мой скрипт делает ровно то, что ему предназначено. Я уже отвечал уважаемому коллеге, но видно вы как-то очень выборочно читаете/воспринимаете ответы. Повторю  для вас: "это подсказка, а не решение". Предполагалось, что человек хоть чуть-чуть  знакомый с Python посмотрит образец, возьмет его за основу и подправит что-бы решить нужную задачу. Но для этого, разумеется, надо сначала хоть одну книжку по Python даже не прочитать, а просмотреть. А нам некогда, мы хеши ломать собрались. Увы, при таком отношении с вашей стороны за вас писать ответ на ваш вопрос желания нет. Удачи!

Comment: Ваша подсказка была полезна. Спасибо за нее. Просто я не правильно ее воспринял. Добавил исправив ее в скрипт, как вы и сказали она ищет значение. Но мне нужно что-бы искалось несколько значений, а в вашем случае работает поиск только одного значения. Если пытаться добавить еще то летит ошибка. Ну хоть на этом спасибо, буду искать другие варианты.